# Dont add duplicate objects into List

Tags: c#

I cant seem to find a way not to add objects into my list that are the same, I tried .Contains but I just did not get it to work, any other workarounds? I believe I must use a if statement, and have the creation of the object in the else, but how do I do in the if statement?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private const string filnamn = "kontakter.bin";
    Kontakter kontakt;
    private List<Kontakter> kontakter;


    private void buttonLagra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Kontakter nyKontakt = new Kontakter();
            {
                nyKontakt.Telefonnr = textBoxTelefonnr.Text;
                nyKontakt.Namn = textBoxNamn.Text;
            }

            kontakter.Add(nyKontakt);
            listBox1.DataSource = null;
            listBox1.DataSource = kontakter;
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filnamn, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            bf.Serialize(fs, kontakter);
            fs.Close();
        }
```

Comment: The default comparison for reference type is to *only* compare the reference address, not compare the actual content. So you will need to implement custom comparisons to compare two `Kontakter`. For example, by implementing [IEquatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But if you need a list with only unique entries, you might want to consider `HashSet` rather than `List`.

Comment: If `Kontakter` overrides `Equals`+`GetHashCode` or you create a custom `IEqualityComparer<Kontakter>` you can use a `HashSet<Kontakter>` which doesn't allow duplicates and returns `false` from `Add`.

Comment: Check [Remove duplicates from a List in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47752/1488067).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List.Contains(o)` checks whether the object `o` references is in the list. This isn't the case, as you just did `o = new {...}`.

You want to check whether an object containing the same properties is present in the list:

```
if (!kontakter.Any(k => k.Telefonnr == textBoxTelefonnr.Text
                     && k.Namn == textBoxNamn.Text))
{
    kontakter.Add(new {...});
}
```

You can also let your `Kontakter` implement `IEquatable<Kontakter>`, so `.Contains()` does do what you expect it to. See [.Contains on a list of custom class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629124/contains-on-a-list-of-custom-class-objects) for an implementation.

Comment: well here you don't have to make a mistake to get a downvote :)

Comment: not everybody has access to linq, hence why i downvoted. should have commented too, sorry.

Comment: @AaronH: Since when that is a reason to downvote. OP didn't specify he does want it to work with a specific version of .NET so everyonce is free to answer.

Comment: why confuse code reading with linq when the code is far more readable with fully expanded code (especially when learning)

Comment: @AaronH I don't think a `foreach` with a helper variable and a `break` and an `if (temp == null) { ... }` check is more readable, as there's a lot more going on than in `.Any()`.

Comment: no need to think about it then. life's too short. peace.

Answer (score 0):

List.Contains wouldn't work because you need to implement an equals method in the class definition.
At the end, try `List<Kontakter> distinct = kontakter.Distinct().ToList();`
Be sure to include System.Linq!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to override the definition of Equals on Kontakter and then define the logic of equal objects. Without overriding .NET compare the object type which is always different because we do the New key word.Sample code on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
            public class Kontakter {
             public bool override Equals(Object obj) {    
                       var castedObj  = (Kontakter)obj;
                       return castedObj.PropertyOne == this.ProperyOne &&  castedObj.Property2 == this.Property2
                   }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1 with Linq's Any:

```
if(!kontakte.Any(k => k.Telefonnummer != myKontakt.Telefonnummer 
                    && k.Name != myKontakt.Name))
    kontakte.Add(nyKontakt);
```

### Solution 2 implement Equals on Kontakt class:

```
public class Kontakt
{  
   public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
   {
      Kontakt other = obj as Kontakt;

      if (other == null) 
         return false;    

      return other.Telefonnummer == this.Telefonnummer 
            && other.Name == this.Name;
   }
}
```

Then you can use

```
if(!kontakte.Contains(myKontakt))
    kontakte.Add(myKontakt);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if exists with a key, for example the name:

```
    private void buttonLagra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Kontakter nyKontakt = new Kontakter();
        {
            nyKontakt.Telefonnr = textBoxTelefonnr.Text;
            nyKontakt.Namn = textBoxNamn.Text;
        }

        bool exists = false;
        foreach (var item in kontackter)
        {
            if (item.Namn == nyKontakt.Namn)
            {
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!exists)
        {
            kontakter.Add(nyKontakt);
            listBox1.DataSource = null;
            listBox1.DataSource = kontakter;
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filnamn, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            bf.Serialize(fs, kontakter);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach and check the current textbox entry is not your list before adding a new item to your list..

```
 bool found = false;

 foreach(Kontakter thisKontakt in kontakter)
 {
     if ((thisKontakt.Telefonnr == textBoxTelefonnr.Text) && (thisKontakt.Namn == textBoxNamn.Text))
     {
         found = true;
         break;
     }
 }

 if(!found)
 {
     kontakter.Add(thisKontakt);
 }
```

Comment: edited to find item in loop and set item outside of loop as per PH's suggestion. Thanks for your input PH, very kind.